# How do I exclude multiple strings in an html input pattern regex?

Tags: html, regex, validation, input

I'd like a regex that will mark email addresses matching certain strings as invalid. I've seen some similar questions, but haven't been able to adapt the regex to work as I hoped.

In it's most simple example form, I thought this pattern:

```
<input type="email" pattern="(?!freesite\.com|\.domain2\.org)">
```

would mark addresses like user@freesite.com and user@subdomain.domain2.org as invalid, but it's not working like I expected.

What regex should I be using?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern - your 'pattern' must match the entire string.

Comment: Use `pattern="\S*@(?!.*(?:freesite\.com|\.domain2\.org)$)\S*"` or something like that.